# R Pearson's vs Spearman's vs Kendall's, P values and correlation

Tags: r, correlation, data-visualization

I am trying to work out how to present data in a graph and whether or not the same data is valid for a correlation test(s).

I am trying to work out if there is an association between age in years and the browser used for online shopping. This is completely hypothetical scenario, with generated data. The sample size is quite small (50).

The below dput shows the age in years of 50 people

```
 dput(as.numeric(Final_DF$age))
c(49, 47, 53, 45, 49, 51, 45, 45, 51, 43, 49, 51, 45, 49, 37, 
45, 47, 59, 55, 39, 53, 51, 43, 51, 49, 47, 41, 53, 49, 39, 47, 
51, 55, 43, 59, 49, 53, 57, 47, 41, 55, 47, 53, 41, 57, 43, 49, 
57, 55, 61)
```

This dput shows the browser used (chrome = 1, internet explorer = 2, firefox = 3, netscape = 4)

```
    dput(DF7$as.numeric.Final_DF.web_browser.)
c(1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1)
```

I am testing normality of the data, P value of the web browser is less than 0.05 meaning data isn't in normal distribution?

```
   # Shapiro-Wilk normality test for age
shapiro.test(as.numeric(Final_DF$age)) #p = 0.7213
# Shapiro-Wilk normality test for browser used
shapiro.test(DF7$as.numeric.Final_DF.web_browser.) # p-value = 6.045e-07 ???????
```

If I conduct Pearson test

```
    cor.test((as.numeric(Final_DF$age)), DF7$as.numeric.Final_DF.web_browser., method = "pearson")

Pearson's product-moment correlation
data:  (as.numeric(Final_DF$age)) and DF7$as.numeric.Final_DF.web_browser.
t = 0.73356, df = 48, p-value = 0.4668
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1782808  0.3727162
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.1052919 

Kendall's rank correlation tau

data:  (as.numeric(Final_DF$age)) and DF7$as.numeric.Final_DF.web_browser.
z = 0.87137, p-value = 0.3836
alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      tau 
0.0987005
```

`Spearman's rank correlation rho` (I have to untie the data for this to work)

```
data:  (as.numeric(Final_DF$age)) and DF7$as.numeric.Final_DF.web_browser.
S = 18268, p-value = 0.3956
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.1227887
```

Plotting [image: Gives me this plot]

```
 ggscatter(DF8, x = "as.numeric(Final_DF$age)", y = "as.numeric.Final_DF.web_browser.", 
                    add = "reg.line", 
                    conf.int = TRUE, 
                    cor.coef = TRUE, 
                    cor.method = "kendall",
                    shape = 20,
                    add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"),
                    xlab = "Age", ylab = "browser")
```

Am I conducting the right tests? Am I interpreting the results correctly - i.e. the p values are higher than 0.05 and therefore we accept the null hypothesis meaning there is no correlation between age and browser type.  Eyeballing the data this is what am I expecting, and it may be that such analysis is not valid or appropriate.

Comment: Is this `ggscatter` from the package `ggpubr`? Please make that clear in text or code, for example by writing it as `ggpubr::ggscatter`

Comment: Web browser is a nominal variable with arbitrary numeric values. There is no sense in which a normal distribution is a reference distribution for such a variable, or in which a correlation or regression with that as one variable has any statistical meaning. What you could try is to compare different age distributions for each browser, say with a Kruskal-Wallis test.

Comment: yes it was ggscatter

Comment: Thanks @NickCox I'll take a look see if I can figure out how to do this on R